# maven+gwt+eclipse

Tags: java, hibernate, gwt, maven

It appears I have a problem configuring `maven` in eclipse. i've installed through eclipse marketplace maven for eclipse and `maven` wtp and it eclipse won't recognize the first line of the POM. not to mention the `<packaging>js</packaging>` part
the error for the first line:

```
"Project build error: Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:javascript-maven-plugin:2.0.0-alpha-1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not transfer artifact org.sonatype.aether:aether-util:jar:1.11 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): No response received after 60000"
```

this is the full `pom.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>www.bgusched.co.il</groupId>
<artifactId>bgusched1</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>JavaScript RIA</name>
<packaging>js</packaging>
<description>A JavaScript Rich Internet Application using jQuery and jQuery UI.</description>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <org.springframework.version>3.0.1.RELAESE</org.springframework.version>
    <org.hibernate.version.>3.5.1-Final</org.hibernate.version.>
    <gwt.version>2.0.3</gwt.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery-amd</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1-alpha-1</version>
        <type>js</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery-ui-amd</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.16-alpha-1</version>
        <type>js</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>$(org.springframework.version)</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>$(org.springframework.version)</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>$(org.hibernate.version)</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>$(org.hibernate.version)</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>$(org.hibernate.version)</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>javascript-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-alpha-1</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
</build>

<!-- FIXME: Temporary declaration of Codehaus repos until this moves to Maven Central -->
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>JBoss</id>
    <name>JBoss Repsitory</name>
    <layout>default</layout>
    <url>http://repository.jboss.org/maven2</url>
</repository>
    <repository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <url>https://nexus.codehaus.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <url>https://nexus.codehaus.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

i've taken it from some online tutorial for building `hibernate-gwt-maven` project

Comment: First of all you didn't close `<project>` tag.

Comment: i did. just didn't copy that. Am a rookie, but not that much of a rookie :) thanks anyway

Comment: Did you make any progress?

Comment: I'm having a major trouble making this thing operate properly
I couldn't find any pom.xml that would solve everything - that is to make both gwt and hibernate compile in my project. Am clueless

Comment: Is your requirement just hibernate + gwt or spring,jquery etc!!!!

Comment: I have no clue. I'm using jpa tags and gwt. My gwt isn't causing any compilation problems only hibernate and jpa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It proably means you do not have javascript-maven-plugin-2.0.0-alpha-1.jar and aether-util-1.11.jar in your local or global maven repos.

You can find available javascript-maven-plugin and aether-util version at central repo [here](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.sonatype.aether%7Caether-util%7C1.13.1%7Cjar). Try downloading and installing them to your local m2 repo.

**Note -** They seem to be optional and I believe you can ditch the extension tag entirely from build tag. They might only help in compressing/cleaning up jquery js files ( ignore them for now )